# Is it possible easily replace a lot of values (strings with numbers) with 2 times it's size

Tags: intellij-idea, replace, notepad++

I have a pretty large project with hundreds of files and folders. They all contain lines that include something like

```
value="23"
```

or

```
value="62923"
```

Is is possible to just match them with regex like `value="([0-9]+)"` and then just replace everything found with, for example two times the number?

I have found the replace functions in IntelliJ and Notepad++ to be very powerful but I haven't been capable of doing this.

Example:

```
value="2" becomes value="4"
value="55" becomes value="110"
```

I have about 20k cases of these across hundreds of files that would be cool to auto-replace.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Structural Search and Replace](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html).
[image]

Edit resultString's `Script text` to `Integer.valueOf(string.getValue())*2`
[image]